# fake loading icon jquery blur function

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

I want to have the following effect: the blur method shows for 1 sec a loading gif beside the form and afterwards the browser shows a yes/no icon. When i try this code the browser shows the yes/no icon and the loading gif together. Another problem comes when i click in a quick succession in the form and the tab button. Then the browser shows more type of the same icon in a row.

**HTML**

```
<form name="field" method="post" id="form">
    <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
    <input name="username" id="username" type="text"/>   
    <span id="img"></span><br><br>
    <input name="submit" type="button" value="Register" id="submit"/><br>   <br>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#username").blur(test);

    function test(){
        $("#img").empty();
        $('<img src=images/loader.gif>').prependTo("#img").fadeOut(1000);
        $('<img src=images/no.png>').prependTo("#img");     
    });
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want timed events to happen synchronously, in other words : you want the yes/no to appear after the 1 second animation. You could time these events, or since you are using jQuery look into the [jQuery fadeOut-documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) to see how you can assign a function to execute AFTER the fade out has completed.

That however, will lead you to the solution for this problem, but it is good to understand what is going on and how callback handlers can help you. Subdividing your application logic in separate functions with internal logic for when they are completed (for instance, an animation completes after its given duration has passed (for instance the 1 sec for the loading GIF), but the *instruction* that starts the animation has finished immediately after the animation starts. You could for instance have a function like so :

```
function showLoadingGIF( aCompleteHandler )
{
    // grab reference to loading animation (say, a DIV with background GIF)
    var loader = document.getElementById( "loader" );

    // set it to visible
    loader.style[ "visibility" ] = "visible";

    // wait for 1000 ms (1 second) before executing this inline code
    setTimeout( function()
    {
        // make loading animation invisible again
        loader.style[ "visibility" ] = "hidden";

         // call complete handler (when passed to this function)
         if ( aCompleteHandler ) 
             aCompleteHandler();

    }, 1000 );
}
```

Then you can call this function and pass ANOTHER function to it, that will be executed when the first animation finishes. I.e.

```
var someFunction = function() {
    alert( "1 second has passed!");
}

showLoadingGIF( someFunction );
```

which will show a dialog box saying "1 second has passed" exactly one second after the loading GIF has been made visible. This is similar to using the callback function of the jQuery fadeout method.

Now as for your problem where multiple clicks on the button prepend multiple images, this is down to your blur-handler prepending a new image to the  with id "image", you could for instance already HAVE an image ready (see example function above) and use CSS to toggle its visibility. Alternatively (and preferredly) you could disable the calling of the animations WHILE they are visible by setting a boolean. This is good practice as it indicates to your application that some operation cannot be started, because a previous (unfinished) operation hasn't finished yet.